# What are benefits/importance for protected question?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, protected-questions

I want to know what the benefits/advantages are of protecting a question? Because only preventing to answer by <10 reputation seems not so effective/efficient (as 10 reputation can easily be achieved for user with 1 rep. ex: if only 5 suggested edits approved!)

So, there should be suitable advantages and importance for protected questions. Maybe future request to update or apply new effective similar to protection so that standard and canonical questions (essential part of information/knowledge based Questions) can be **secured**!

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be a large barrier to posting, it just needs to be *large enough* to prevent spammy answers. People who want to post a "thanks!" answer aren't going to try and get the 10 rep needed to be able to do it.

Comment: purpose of this feature, as well as why the rep limit is 10, have been explained in SE blog: [New Protected Question Status](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/): _"...if you see a question that is attracting a lot of drive-by noise answers, please flag it for moderator attention. We’ll turn on protection. The protection bar is extraordinarily low right now — you only need >= 10 reputation to post an answer to a protected question — but we think this is enough to cut down dramatically on answer noise for certain unlucky, but obviously popular, questions."_